# SQL debugging in large PHP app

Tags: php, sql

I am using CodeCharge Studio to finish a large PHP application.  This question isn't really CCS related, but a bit more general.  I have a web form that is supposed to allow CRUD capabilities with a certain SQL Server table, but the Inserts keep failing without throwing any errors.  What would be the best way to debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I'm having trouble with dynamically generated SQL queries, I typically echo out the query and try running that query on the console for the DB.  Or alternatively, you could write a simple PHP function that writes out strings to a file, and that way you don't have to display the query directly on your page, but instead in a log file.

Answer (score 5):

See what the actually query is and then try doing that query directly on the DB. Then you know whether it's a PHP issue or a DB issue.

Then go from there, depending on the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

If the query looks OK, double check that the user running the query has **insert** rights to the database.

I've been caught out by that before.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor all sql queries in mysql as shown in this [site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/), once you enable logging, run the query manually and see why its failing..this should be good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what's mentioned before, I can add my recent discovery:

> trigger_error(print_r($your_var,1),E_USER_ERROR);

So you can output and debug your variable, even if it's a complex script with redirects, where simple echo would not help.

Dmitri.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) and log all the SQL to your Firebug:

An Example would be:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {

    // In un successfull log to FireBug

    FB::error($data, "SQL error: ".mysql_error());

}`

You can also implement the FB::error call from your own function, so you can later deactivate this behaviour modifying your function:

`function log_error($data, $msg){

 //dont forget to deactivate in case the application goes live!

 FB::error($data, $msg);

}

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {

  // In un successfull log to FireBug

  log_error($data, "SQL error: ".mysql_error());

}`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the database connection classes in CodeCharge have a 'debug' flag which will automatically write all the page's database commands at the top of the page.

For example, in an old PHP project of mine, 'Common Files' the file 'db_mysql.php' (line 27):

```
public $Debug         = 0;     ## Set to 1 for debugging messages.
```

Change to '1' and publish that file. Load the web page. Change back and re-publish when done.

I've used this in CCS for PHP and ASP projects, and is likely in the other languages (not sure if or where to find in .NET projects).